# How to make iteration on wpdb->update or query statement?

Tags: wpdb

I want to change post_names with iteration; I have similar post names and want to change them by `foreach` iteration.

Initial post name is "one-book" and there are 30 similar names. I want to change names to: "one-book-1", "one-book-2", "one-book-3" ... "one-book-30", but `wpdb->update` and `wpdb->query` only return **"one-book-1" *30 times*.**

```
$postname = "one-book";
$i = 1;
$count = 30;
while ($i <= $count) {
    $postnewname[] = "$postname-$i";
    $i++;
}

foreach ($postnewname as $one_postnewname) { 
    // Tried this one but it didn't work.
    // $update = $wpdb->update( 
    //     "xx_posts", 
    //     array( "post_name" => $one_postnewname), 
    //     array( "post_name" => $postname ) 
    // ); 

    // This is also didn't work as expected.        
    $wpdb->query("
        update xx_posts 
        SET post_name='$one_postnewname' 
        where post_name='$postname'
    ");
}
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: And `$postname` is defined where...?

Comment: sorry forgot `$postname = "one-book"`